# Order relation with predecessors and successors

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Is there a name for a total order in which every element has both a predecessor and a successor?

If $(T,\leq)$ is a total order and $x\in T$, then the successor of $x$ is the minimum of $\{y\in T:y>x\}$ and the predecessor is the maximum of $\{y\in T:y<x\}$, if they exist.

I know that these orders are all of the form $R\times\mathbb{Z}$ with the lexicographic ordering for some total order $R$; here I'm just looking for a nomenclature, if it exists.

Comment: Please don't add 3 tags to the system for no reason.

Comment: What do you mean by "add 3 tags to the system for no reason"? I tried to use tags which seemed appropriate. I'm not a native speaker, so "terminology" didn't occur to me as a better alternative for "nomenclature".

Comment: You added 3 tags that weren't in the system, meaning someone had to go clean them up. I'm also not a native speaker.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what do you mean by "someone had to go clean them up". Why is the cleanup required? Weren't they relevant? What is the problem? Probably I'm missing something trivial, sorry :) I also don't want to waste your time, so feel free to ignore this. I just thought it was good practice to put tags so that other people might find more easily the question by searching for "order", "relation", etc...

Comment: When there are tags that mean the same thing but are different tags, people tend to use one or the other, which means that users filtering by a tag can't see all of the questions by that tag. More importantly, tags like "order" are far too vague, and can be used by novices just learning about the natural numbers, or experts in a variety of fields. That's why most established tags have wikis, excerpts, and descriptive names explaining their usage and purpose.